# update dictionary and compare to new items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input, text-files

Ok so I am completely lost for this problem, please help me. I have already created a function that takes in a text file and sorts all the names into the text file, puts them in a dictionary. So my new dictionary looks like this:

```
namesDict = {'J': ['Jacob', 'Joshua'], 'T': ['Tyler'], 'A': ['Austin'], 'B': ['Brandon'], 'D': ['Daniel'], 'M': ['Michael', 'Matthew'], 'C': ['Christopher'], 'N': ['Nicholas']}
```

now I have to take in this dictionary I created and add new names. The new function has to do this

The function will ask the user to input their name. Assume the user will enter names with a capital first letter, and all lowercase letters after that.
If their name is already in the dictionary, print “[name] is already in the dictionary”, and then return the same dictionary.
If their name is not already in the dictionary, then you will add their name to the dictionary under the appropriate key, print “[name] added to dictionary”, and then return the updated dictionary.
If their name is not already in the dictionary AND the first letter of their name is not already a key in the dictionary, then you will add the first letter of their name as a key, with a list containing their name as the value. You will then print “[name] added to dictionary”, and return the updated dictionary.

so I have this so far which of course is not complete:

```
def updateDictionary(namesDict):
    newname= input('What is your name?')
    if newname = key:
        print(newname'is already in the dictionary')

    elif newname != key:
        print (newname 'added to dictionary')

    elif newname = key[0]:
        print (newname 'added to dictionary')
```

also my first code to create the dictionary from the text file is this:

```
def newDictionary():
    names={}
    file = open('file.txt','r')
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    if len(lines) == 1 and len(lines[0]) == 0:
        print('empty file')
    else:
        for line in lines:
            if line in names:
                names[(line[0])].append(line)
            else:
                names[(line[0])] = [line,] 
    return names
```

but i am having an error in this code which says  names[(line[0])] = [line,]
IndexError: string index out of range.

PLEASE PLEASE help me out. I don't know how to take in the new input name and put it in the dictionary. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you post the contents of the file you are reading?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting `IndexError` for this line:

```
[(line[0])] = [line,]
```

it means that there is no first (`line[0]`) character in the line - in other words, the line is blank. So you need to ignore blank lines

updating the dictionary can be done as follows:

```
def updateDictionary(namesDict):
    newname = input('What is your name?')
    key = newname[0]

    if key not in namesDict:
        namesDict[key] = []

    item = namesDict[key]

    if newname in item:
        print(newname, 'is already in the dictionary')
    else:
        item.append(newname)
        print(newname, 'added to dictionary')

    return namesDict
```

Comment: downvote. because there is no any fancy Python stuff going on in this answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

Your `newDictionary()` cannot produce the dictionary because probably there is an empty line in your file.

### Solution:

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will make things easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def newDictionary():
    names = defaultdict(list)
    with open('file.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                names[line[0]].append(line)
    return names
```